# Trouble adding Obj-C++ subproject into a Xcode Obj-C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, objective-c++, armv7

I created a Objective-C++ project that runs some C++ (OpenCV) code. It runs fine and everything works well. But then I decided to add these routines as a subproject to my MAIN PROJECT, I get errors whenever I try to use the subproject classes.

The thing is, my SUBPROJECT uses **.mm** source files whereas my MAIN PROJECT uses only **.m** source files: [image]

Every time I try to allocate a the class DyOpenCV (`DyOpenCv *opencv = [DyOpenCv alloc]`), I get a lot of errors: [image: Compilation errors]

Is that a tip to merge Obj-C with Obj-Cpp projects? 
Is that a special interface to use, once I am trying to run **.mm** files from **.m** ones? Even if the **.mm** files are from a subproject?
Is it necessary to add all libraries of my subproject to my project (I already did that)?

Cheers,

Comment: Look at those missing symbols. You have to link against the C++ standard library. Change the linker from `clang` to `clang++` and it'll work fine.

Comment: It didn't worked, H2CO3.  I am actually in the way of this tutorial: http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects that seems to teach what to do when in these situations. I will post back here if it works for me =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link against the c++ standard library. This normally happens automatically if your compile sources phase contains any c++ files, but if the c++ is all contained within a static library then you need to explicitly ask for it to be linked to the final executable.

Check the subproject's build settings. Look for the C++ Standard Library build option. If it's set to libc++ (llvm standard library), then add `-lc++` to your application's additional linker flags. If it's set to libstdc++ (gnu library), then add `-lstdc++` to your application's additional linker flags.

Comment: I did that and a series of other errors appeared. In my Obj-C project, everywhere there was a `@property(nonatomic strong)...` line, a bug appeared because of this strong thing. I am more attracted to this solution: http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects but there is no guarantee it will work.

Comment: Are you sure you only changed the linker flags? What you've described sounds like an issue with compilation, not linking (which is what your original error was).

Comment: You was right. I just added `-lc++` to my **Other Linker Flags** and changed my **Standard Library** to `libc++`, as you suggested.